# SQL Server : return 3 items

Tags: sql, sql-server

Short version: I need to return a query with 3 items from another table and adding it to the existing table.

Long version:

`Table A` contains the following information:

```
| ID | Name | Date |  Comment  |
--------------------------------
| 1  | AJ   | 9/11 | Howdy     |
| 2  | AW   | 9/13 | Hi        |
| 3  | AK   | 9/15 | Aloha     |
| 4  | AW   | 9/15 | Hello     |
| 5  | AJ   | 9/18 | Greetings |
```

I need `Table B` to resemble:

```
| ID |  Comment  |  Comment2  |  Comment3  |
--------------------------------------------
| 1  | Howdy     |  Aloha     |  Greetings |
```

I am running

```
SELECT TOP 3 * 
FROM a 
WHERE Name IN ('AJ','AK')
```

but that makes `Table B` appear like:

```
| ID | Name | Date |  Comment  |
--------------------------------
| 1  | AJ   | 9/11 | Howdy     |
| 3  | AK   | 9/15 | Aloha     |
| 5  | AJ   | 9/18 | Greetings |
```

Is it even possible to get what I want?

Comment: Are you trying to get the result from code? If so what language?

Comment: @ohmusama trying to get a result from crystal reports XI

Comment: @Andrew The ID field is irrelevant. I would like to just have the 3 items appear in a single row and return at the same time.

Comment: But ID only has one comment (howdy).  Why do you want to associate it with the other values?

Comment: If you have code access, it would be better just to select out the comments, and join them yourself. Rows in SQL MEAN unique ideas, Columns are attributes to that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are after as you have id's for each comment, then your output has a single row with an id (where does this id come from for your output?) but this may be able to be expanded upon:

```
SELECT
  [1] AS COMMENT1,
  [2] AS COMMENT2,
  [3] AS COMMENT3
FROM
  TABLE_A
PIVOT (MAX(COMMENT) FOR id IN ([1],[2],[3])) AS PVT
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this , it helpful to you

```
  select b.id, b.comment as comment
, (select comment from ##temp1 where id = b.id+2 )  as comment1
, (select comment from ##temp1 where id = b.id+4 )  as comment2
  from  ##temp1 b  where b.id=1
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this will work, but i'm just throwing the idea here. Let me know if it works!

```
   Insert into B Values (
    ( SELECT TOP 3 comment FROM a WHERE Name IN ('AJ','AK') limit 1 ),
    ( SELECT TOP 3 comment FROM a WHERE Name IN ('AJ','AK') limit 1,1 ),
    ( SELECT TOP 3 comment FROM a WHERE Name IN ('AJ','AK') limit 2,1 )
    )
```

**This is for MySQL. please change accordingly for MSSQL Server**

Comment: MSSQL Server doesn't support the `limit` clause. However, if he was to use your idea, SQL server 2012 does support the `OFFSET FETCH` clause

Comment: i forgot to check the tags.. although i just wanted to let him know that something like this is possible..